# DataGridView column DateTimePicker in vb.net C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

I am using a DataGridView inner DateTimePicker, but it is not working properly.
It can only select the year or month and the calendar control is closed.
How do I to select the year & month & date?

Comment: add code here to support

Answer (score 2):

Try this code (c# code)

```
DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();  //DateTimePicker
Rectangle _Rectangle;

public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        dataGridView2.Controls.Add(dtp);
        dtp.Visible = false;  //  
        dtp.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;  //2010-08-05  
        dtp.TextChanged += new EventHandler(dtp_TextChange);


    }

private void dataGridView2_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (dataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name)
        {
            case "dateAchatDataGridViewTextBoxColumn1":

                _Rectangle = dataGridView2.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true); //  
                dtp.Size = new Size(_Rectangle.Width, _Rectangle.Height); //  
                dtp.Location = new Point(_Rectangle.X, _Rectangle.Y); //  
                dtp.Visible = true;  

                break;

        }
    }


    private void dtp_TextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView2.CurrentCell.Value = dtp.Text.ToString();  
    }  

    private void dataGridView2_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)  
    {  
        dtp.Visible = false;  

    }  


    private void dataGridView2_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)  
    {  
        dtp.Visible = false;  
    }
```

Comment: how to declare Rectangle

Comment: Rectangle _Rectangle;

Comment: Using System.Drawing not support Rectangle

Answer (score 0):

This is answer:
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    private DateTimePicker cellDateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker();
    DateTimePicker[] sp = new DateTimePicker[100];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt=new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Start-Date", typeof(DateTime)));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {


        sp[e.RowIndex] = new DateTimePicker();

        if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Start-Date")
        {
            this.cellDateTimePicker = sp[e.RowIndex];
            this.cellDateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
                this.cellDateTimePicker.Name = "sp[" + e.RowIndex + "]";
         //   this.cellDateTimePicker.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(cellDateTimePickerValueChanged);
            this.cellDateTimePicker.Visible = true;
            this.cellDateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
            this.cellDateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
             this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(cellDateTimePicker);
            System.Drawing.Rectangle tempRect = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);
            cellDateTimePicker.Location = tempRect.Location;
            cellDateTimePicker.Width = tempRect.Width;
 dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy";
          this.cellDateTimePicker.Visible = true;

        }
    }
}
```